# how can i Encrypt a decrypted zte zxhn h108n V2.5 config file?

Tags: decryption, encryption, python

i have decrypted  the config file [using a program i found online](https://www110.zippyshare.com/v/K4IYzLDk/file.html) ( maybe made by python to exe )

so to decrypt using it you type is command into CMD

```
decode_zte_config.exe config.bin config.bin.xml --key "GrWM2Hz&LTvz&f^5"
```

how can i encrypt the config file after editing it to upload it to the router and disable some unwanted settings .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [zcu](https://github.com/streetster/zte-config-utility) module to do this.

```
python examples/encode.py config.bin.xml out.bin --key 'GrWM2Hz&LTvz&f^5' --signature 'ZXHN H108N V2.5'
```

Full disclosure: I wrote the `zcu` module. It's based off of [this](https://pastebin.com/GGxbngtK) pastebin.